# Rails activation route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I am learning rails and routing has me wanting to jump off the roof.
  I am confused on how to go about routing my activation at this point.
I have the following currently in my user routing:
`resources :users, only: [:new,:create,:show]`.  Now I want a route to `Users#activate` like this `www.app.com/users/activate/:a_long_token`. Now I know I can just simply do a `match '/activate/:auth_token', to: 'users#activate` but I am not sure whether this is convention. I was reading [this](http://www.funonrails.com/2010/08/actionmailer-smtp-settings-in-rails.html) guide on user authentication but it seems its routing is rails 2. Can I do something to add the route mentioned above by simply adding something to the resource itself. By that I mean doing something like (I know this won't work)

```
resource :users do 
   member do
     get :activate
   end
 end
```

Comment: you need to pass it as a collection.  As a rule, anything that uses a resource's id is under a member, anything else is under a collection.  You can try `get :activate, on: :collection` but you need to pass `:auth_token` as a params so your url will look like `/users/activate?auth_token=...`.  Use match if you want to use the prettier version of the url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

rails3 guide
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

```rb
resources :users do 
  collection do
    get "activate/:a_long_token" => "users#activate", as: :activate
  end
end
```

`rake routes` outputs this

```
activate_users GET    /users/activate/:a_long_token(.:format) users#activate
```